# Kusto - range colors for values

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am converting a Splunk dashboard to a Kusto Dashboard in ADX. Below is from the splunk query to format the dashboard values with colors based on their value range. I would like to do the same in Kusto Dash board. I am able to use conditional fomrating in the Visual option. But is there a way to include this in the Kusto Query. Thanks.

````
        <option name="rangeValues">[100,160,190]</option>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today there is no built-in way in the query to format the visual text color.
The only way is through the visual formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: How do you set color on columns in a columnchart in Kusto?